# PDF - Nameddest used in Hyperlink

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

After searching through this forum I still have not found an answer. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

For a project I need to link to a specific destination in a PDF file. Adding "#page=xx" to the hyperlink currently works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. But since the document is changing in time this solution is not too flexible.

I want to use the "#nameddest" in stead of the pagenumber. I created Word document with headings and a page index and saved it as a PDF including bookmarks. In Chrome this solution works perfectly taking me to the correct context in the PDF file. But I can't seem to use this in Edge.

Is there a multi-browser solution to link to a specific paragraph, without the need of adding the pagenumber?

Comment: Are you testing on Edge Legacy? I test on Edge Legacy and can reproduce the issue. I also test on Edge Chromium and it works well with nameddest on it. I suggest that you update your browser to [the new Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/download-the-new-microsoft-edge-based-on-chromium-0f4a3dd7-55df-60f5-739f-00010dba52cf) as end of support for Edge Legacy is on March 9, 2021. You can refer to the [Lifecycle policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge#what-is-the-lifecycle-policy-for-microsoft-edge).

Comment: I confirm, nameddest does not work in Edge Chromium Version 87.0.664.47 (Official build) (64-bit).   I opened exactly same link in Google Chrome and it jumped to the destination properly.

Comment: I indeed use Edge Chromium - as do most of the user in my UAT. In Chrome it is working perfectly fine. Is there any workaround To fix it? Or should I focus on implementing the pagenumber solution?

Comment: Can you please try to open this link in Edge Chromium to see if it works: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#nameddest=Contents. It uses nameddest and works fine in my Edge. Please also check my test result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpQ7o.gif.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of browsers is a constantly changing one and that includes their PDF binary extensions. So this answer is after the status at the time of Original Posting and may well be different tomorrow as you may bee rolled out an update that affects Edge ability.

[Update]
The best way to test this function is the Key Document itself so here is a link to nammeddest F4. Remember these are NOT page numbers (page=5) NOR bookmarks NOR outline entries NOR text content. Simply these are imbedded named areas in a PDF, (A destination with a name like Tokyo Airport or its environs).

**So F4 is an area on page 5 in a specific PDF** test it here (Adobe PDF on Microsoft.com)
https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE4Pb5n#nameddest=F4

However there are others on Page 5 such as :-
https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE4Pb5n#nameddest=G4.1501771

And this where diferent behaviours show up.
Most major browsers Edge (Without "Powered by Acrobat"), Chrome and most Chromium variants like Brave, FireFox, versions 100+ should respect #nameddest well.

Many other browsers may or may not function in the same way. The  URL fragment code was designed by Adobe to pass parameters to their earlier Acrobat PDF plugins. And yet DOES NOT currently work With Acrobat Lite in Edge!

So what can be different Try that
https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE4Pb5n#nameddest=G4.1501771
in different browsers

### Chrome

[image]

### Edge

[image]

### Firefox

[image]

So Edge is not so advanced. However there are other oddities.

Some Viewers will extend the nameddest ability to the sidebars and Chrome goes one further by seeking destinations by body text.

Here Chrome responds to "Parameters" in the headings although it is NOT a named  destination.
[image]
and Edge will go to that page
[image]
But FireFox  rightly does not find that false nameddest
[image]

However Firefox can search and highlight.
[image]

The most reliable way to designate a destination is by zooming a viewport in a numbered page. And keeping an updated index of those zoom destinations.